# What PHP framework can work with doctrine 2?

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, orm, frameworks

I saw many recommendations on doctrine 2 but I wonder how to use it. Most frameworks are bonded with certain ORM and I am not sure if they can work with doctrine 2.

Or if you choose to use doctrine 2, you can't use a framework then? Sorry for the silly question.

Comment: Most mainstream frameworks can work with Doctrine, though they mostly don't include it as standard

Comment: A lot of frameworks outthere are modular, and does not require you to use their default ORM ! Laravel for instance, you can use another ORM other than Eloquent.

Comment: Oh, thank you all. That helps.

Comment: http://symfony.com/doc/current/doctrine.html

Comment: @Cerad. I reckon that is doctrine, not doctrine 2?

Comment: @bijiDango - I reckon you be wrong.